# Cast SqlDouble to double? type causes SqlDouble.Value to raise null value exception

Tags: c#, casting, nullreferenceexception, sqlgeometry

I am trying to construct a linestring using SqlGeometryBuilder.

```
SqlGeometry point = line.STPointN(x)
gb.BeginFigure((double)point.X, (double)point.Y, (double?)point.Z, (double?)point.M);
```

The .Z and .M properties of the `SqlGeometry` return as type `SqlDouble`, so I tried casting them both to `double?`. However, casting these properties seems to call `.Value` on the property which will throw a null exception rather than returning null, breaking my code.

Is there a way to cast which doesn't invoke `.Value` for the SqlGeometry Z and M values?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can this help?

```
SqlGeometry point = line.STPointN(x)
gb.BeginFigure((double)point.X, (double)point.Y, point.HasZ ? (double?)point.Z : (double?)null, point.HasM ? (double?)point.M : (double?)null );
```

Comment: Yep that should do it. Thanks :)